# HtmlWebpackPlugin putting all script tags in one line?

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

why is this code putting all the script tags in one line? It looks ugly, please help me

first it was putting everything on one line but now its only putting script tags in one line

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        index: './src/index.js',
        lol: './src/lol.js',
        kush: "./src/kush.js"
      },
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Output Management',
            inject:   "body",
            minify: { collapseWhitespace: false },
        }),
      ],
    output: {  
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, and my solution is not to use inject,
but handle it manually using `htmlWebpackPlugin.tags`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.headTags.join('\n    ') %>
</head>
<body
    <div>
        <!-- some html content -->
    </div>
    <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.tags.bodyTags.join('\n    ') %>
</body>
</html>
```

it will create a result like :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
    <link href="assets/css/93b7166d870a29a6fad6.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Oo8gaHXRDnVLTy8gdmWUpQdtthZTVqhZKX+kdXoWAy17bo/rKv82S8Cx5jb++Sit" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- some html content -->
    </div>
    <script src="assets/js/2a9ca03ee33386c2edb7.bundle.js" integrity="sha384-Xstlc3gJWqqvivogC+OkawDdDb9q5pFH5RuHS4cWVNbPVbSoDgap9ozyIy8DCSQE" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it to format the generated HTML code with line breaks and indentation to make it more readable using the prettier package:

1. First, install prettier package by running the following command:

```
    npm install --save-dev prettier
```

2. In your webpack configuration file, add the following code to configure HtmlWebpackPlugin to use prettier to format the generated HTML

```
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
    const prettier = require('prettier');
    
    module.exports = {
      // ... your other webpack config
      plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          // ... your other HtmlWebpackPlugin options
          templateContent: ({ htmlWebpackPlugin }) => {
            const { html } = htmlWebpackPlugin.options;
            return prettier.format(html, { parser: 'html' });
          },
        }),
      ],
    };
```

3. if your index.html file is in the dist directory, you can run the following command:

```
    npx prettier --write dist/index.html
```

4. This will format the index.html file using prettier and write the formatted code back to the file.